# Overwriting clickhouse-backup default config

Tags: clickhouse

I want to create a backup of my clickhouse database. I'm following the guide [here](https://github.com/AlexAkulov/clickhouse-backup/blob/master/ReadMe.md).

As recommended in the guide I'm using the official tiny docker image for clickhouse-backup. When running for instance:

`$ clickhouse-backup tables`

I'll receive this response:

`can't connect to clickouse with: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9000: connect: connection refused`

Which is why I want to overwrite the default configuration because the port is different. It says in the guide that it is possible via environment variables to overwrite the default options. So I created a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export CLICKHOUSE_PORT=8123
```

But this doesn't change the response for command "$ *clickhouse-backup tables*".

**Am I setting the env variable wrong or is there something else I can do to alter the default config?**

The default config looks like this:

```
johnnylord:/c/DevTools/source/project/clickhouse-backup$ clickhouse-backup default-config

general:
  remote_storage: s3
  disable_progress_bar: false
  backups_to_keep_local: 0
  backups_to_keep_remote: 0
clickhouse:
  username: default
  password: ""
  host: localhost
  port: 9000
  data_path: ""
  skip_tables:
  - system.*
  timeout: 5m
  freeze_by_part: false
s3:
  access_key: ""
  secret_key: ""
  bucket: ""
  endpoint: ""
  region: us-east-1
  acl: private
  force_path_style: false
  path: ""
  disable_ssl: false
  part_size: 104857600
  compression_level: 1
  compression_format: gzip
  sse: ""
  disable_cert_verification: false
gcs:
  credentials_file: ""
  credentials_json: ""
  bucket: ""
  path: ""
  compression_level: 1
  compression_format: gzip
cos:
  url: ""
  timeout: 2m
  secret_id: ""
  secret_key: ""
  path: ""
  compression_format: gzip
  compression_level: 1
  debug: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9000 -- tcp protocol

8123 -- http protocol

You simply cannot use HTTP(8123) instead of TCP(9000).
You have to use ch_tcp protocol.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Rookie mistake from my side.